# IntelliJ and GitHub

Tags: java, version-control, github, intellij-idea

I was wondering if someone would be able to tell me how I can push my updated source code to my github project FROM the IntelliJ IDE.

I have already clicked "Share this project on GitHub" And when I go there, all that's there is
an empty repository.

Comment: After you share the project on github, you should then add files to the, commit them, and push them.

Comment: Yeah when I do that, I get this error: http://prntscr.com/39gu2z